# JS to check for class if exsist and change property

Tags: javascript, css

In the following setup:

```
<div class="div1">
    <p class="class1"></p>
</div>
```

I need a JS that can check if inside "Div1" there is any element with class "class1", and if it does exist, to change padding in "Div1", if does not exist, don't do anything.

Comment: Hi, could you post what you have so far ? Please take note that this is not a coding service. We can help you regarding actual code but won't do eveyrthing for you.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Where is your JS attempt? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you explain more what you want to achieve with this? You could reverse the question and say that all the `class1` paragraphs inside `div1` should have a margin. Which can be expressed in one line of CSS: `.div1 .class1 { margin: 2em; }`.

Comment: Some day we will be able to do `.div1:has(.class1) {}`... we can dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to target the parent and the child element like the following way:

```js
var d = document.querySelector('.div1');
if(d.querySelector('.class1')){
  d.style.padding = '20px';
}
```

```css
.div1{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <p class="class1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, I'm doing this to narrow the bootstrap grid gaps on certain elements only.

Comment: @Boby, you are most welcome:)